# Cannot get Tor proxy to connect on Ubuntu 22.04 jammy --not Tor Browser

Tags: networking, apt, proxy, browser, tor

I cannot get Tor to connect in Chromium or Firefox browser. I want to use Tor on my system and not the Tor Browser. I have used Tor for 13 years, but after updating to 22.04 from 21.10, I cannot get the Tor client to connect in browsers. I am running Ubuntu 22.04 on Asus laptop 64 bit.

I installed Tor in terminal from [Tor website](https://support.torproject.org/apt/tor-deb-repo/). Edited the Tor.list file to include `arch=amd64` to get file recognized when running `# apt update`. I ran `apt update` and then added the gpg key. Then installed Tor and the deb.torproject.org-keyring.

I set laptop Network Proxy settings to Manual with HTTP & HTTPS to 127.0.0.1:8118 and Socks Host 127.0.0.1:9050.  But when I check Tor connection in browser at check.torproject.org, it returns with status that I am not using Tor.

I checked Tor status and get:

```
ss -aln | grep 9050
tcp  LISTEN 0  4096  127.0.0.1:9050  0.0.0.0:*
```

Is this correct?

Lastly, I checked my torrc file against an older saved version from 2017 and the current torrc is dated 2013!  Any help with the right configuration for this installation to work on Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy?  Thanks.

Comment: Tor is available for downloading from the official repositories for 22.04

Comment: @24601, Thanks. I know that Tor Browser is available for download. However, I want to use Tor for my operating system, to redirect all outbound connections in a transparent proxy. So using just the Tor Browser would not be a complete solution.

Comment: Ok. I fix this by changing Privoxy configurations at: **sudo gedit /etc/privoxy/config**.  I had the wrong forwarding address. I found a corrected address on Tor Support for Privoxy and changed it to: **forward-socks5 / localhost:9050 .**  This fixed it so that my browsers now configured to use Tor.